# in r, how can one trim or winsorize data by a factor

Tags: r

I'm trying to apply the winsor function at each level of a factor (subjects) in order to remove extreme cases.  I can apply the winsor function to the entire column, but would like to do it within subject.

```
Subject RT
1       402
1       422
1       155
1       460
2       283
2       224
2       346
2       447
3       415
3       161
3       1
3       343
```

Ideally, I'd like the output to be a vector containing the same number of rows as the input but with outliers (e.g. the second last value of Subject 3) to be removed and replaced as per the winsor function.

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for the `?by` function

```
 #  for example: 
 by(myDF, myDF$Subject, winsor(myDF$RT))
```

However, using `data.table` (instead of `data.frame`) might be better suited for you

```
### broken down step by step: 

library(data.table)
myDT <- data.table(myDF)

myDT[, winsorResult := winsor(RT), by=Subject]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 library(psych)
 transform(dat,win = ave(RT,Subject,FUN=winsor))
   Subject  RT   win
1        1 402 402.0
2        1 422 422.0
3        1 155 303.2
4        1 460 437.2
5        2 283 283.0
6        2 224 259.4
7        2 346 346.0
8        2 447 386.4
9        3 415 371.8
10       3 161 161.0
11       3   1  97.0
12       3 343 343.0
```